# mix will not recompile apps when change "config.exs" in umbrella

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

```
➜ tree
.
├── README.md
├── _build
│   └── dev
│       ├── consolidated
│       │   ├── Elixir.Collectable.beam
│       │   ├── Elixir.Enumerable.beam
│       │   ├── Elixir.IEx.Info.beam
│       │   ├── Elixir.Inspect.beam
│       │   ├── Elixir.List.Chars.beam
│       │   └── Elixir.String.Chars.beam
│       └── lib
│           └── ks
│               └── ebin
│                   ├── Elixir.Ks.beam
│                   └── ks.app
├── apps
│   └── ks
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── config
│       │   └── config.exs
│       ├── lib
│       │   └── ks.ex
│       ├── mix.exs
│       └── test
│           ├── ks_test.exs
│           └── test_helper.exs
├── config
│   └── config.exs
└── mix.exs

12 directories, 17 files
```

this is an umbrella app

and I had added this code in "config/config.exs"

```
import_config "../apps/*/config/config.exs"
```

when I try to change the config in "apps/ks/config/config.exs", and run `"mix compile"`, it will not recompile the ks-app

in my mind, when changed one config file, it should recompile this app and generated new ks app, but it does not work

any suggestion will be helpful, thanks

Comment: Does `mix clean && mix compile ` work?

Comment: @YongHaoHu Yes, up to now, the only way is clean firstly, but you know, the mix clean will delete all the _build, so it will compile other apps again

Comment: I just reproduced this locally. Looks like a bug to me because touching `mix.exs` or any `.ex` file in `apps/*/lib` does trigger a recompile.

Comment: @Dogbert Mix 1.5.2, it's my mix version